# How to configure the rule in sakuli_gearman_proxy.cfg that modify the output of sakuli?

Tags: gearman, sahi

I want to implement a rule which sets the status to WARN in case of a concrete error.Can someone please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are aiming to do with `gearmand`. Could you elaborate your question, please.

Comment: @palik                                                                                                                     decoded =~ s/return_code=2(.*)output=\[CRIT\] .* EXCEPTION:.*(Termin could not be deleted).*\\n/return_code=1$1output=Testcase error as termin could not be deleted\\n/;
This provides 'Status Information in icinga as CRITICAL with red colour want to change it to WARNING with yellow colour